# If $a^2|bc$, does $a|b$ or $a|c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm

Basically, I am trying to prove that $a^2|bc$ implies $a|b$ or $a|c$.

I can visualize it in my head (based on the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and the factors of a,b,c), however, everything I try to write it down/express it in mathematical terms fail.  The closest I’ve gotten is showing $a|bc$, however, that is rather trivial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am clearly missing something.

Comment: Hint: Try $a = 6, b = 4$.

Comment: $4\mid 2\cdot 2$ but ...

Comment: Probably you are thinking of $a$ being a prime number?

Comment: @CalvinLin duh, thanks so much. I tested it in with the first few values of $a$ but now realize I didn’t test anything with the product of two primes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fail for the same reason that $a\mid bc$ does not directly imply that $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$

Consider if $a=pq, b=p^2,c=q^2$ with $p,q$ both prime.